# Transitions jumpy in jQuery mobile phoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an ios app using Phonegap Build and jquery mobile 1.4.2. I'm using the following script to fix jumpy and flickering transitions between pages: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/ff1a7e019f45ad00fc9aa3e0fcb08df5acc54a66

In the beginning of the js file it says:

```
 define( [ "jquery", "./jquery.mobile.core" ], function( $ ) {
```

This line throws an error: `ReferenceError: define is not defined`

I'm not familiar with this "define" syntax, so not sure what is going wrong. I tried to point the path to my jquery mobile file (`jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js`) but the error is still there.

So what does define do, and why is it throwing an error?

Answer (score -1):

you need something before call Jquery mobile js do like this:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
                    {
                       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("ios") != -1)
                       {
                         $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                         $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
                       }
                    });
                    </script>
                    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, the transitions.js file still throws the error, but the flickering s still occurs sometimes when using the back button, but overall maybe a little less jumpiness. Suggestions for the back button?

Comment: confirm if condition fire or not ?

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to fire, I put an alert in the if statement and ran it on my phone but no alert was prompted.

Comment: No, doesnt fire either

Comment: Sorry, mobileinit does trigger, my mistake.

Comment: Nope, stil happens sometimes with back button, but maybe every third time.